# Cannot find Routing and Remote Access

Tags: routing, remote

I have a remote desktop server (Win XP SP3 German), and i need to configure a vpn. However, i cannot find Routing and remote access anywhere - I also tried with Start --> Run --> rrasmgmt.msc, but it says that the file doesn't exists. What is the problem ? Do i need to isntall additional files ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the Windows 2003 Administration Tools.  The download is available from MS [**here**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed the Administrative tools Pack and you can't find the snap-in, recreate it by going to an mmc console:

- go to run>type "mmc"
- go to File: Add/Remote Snap-in,
- click "Add" and find it there.

Comment: I don't see RRAS as an option in my MMC on XP. I guess it would need to be installed separately, but where do you get it from?

Comment: Win 2003 Admin tools pack, as I mentioned before (Just because it's for server 2003 doesn't mean it's not going to work): http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en

Comment: also not an option on windows 10

Answer (score 1):

RRAS is not there in Windows XP. Its on Server OS

for server, try: http://www.winplat.net/post/How-to-install-Remote-and-Routing-Service-(RRAS)-on-Windows-Server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think RRAS is installed on Win XP. " http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655.aspx..." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/network/bb545655.aspx

I doubt it could be installed onto Win XP since that OS is not intended to be a server.

Comment: It is included with WinXP but disabled by default.

Comment: @squillman, do you mean that you need to install the W2k3 resource kit to get it, or there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: No, it is part of WinXP.  To get the MMC snap-in for RRAS admin, though, you need to install the Admin Tools (not the resource kit).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use it for VPN Server or for VPN client?

If for server, remember that XP has limit for 10 inbound TCP connections in the TCP/IP stack! And I'm not entirely sure if RRAS bits in the XP actually contain all the necessary code for server functionality like with w2k3's RRAS..

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to make your XP machine a VPN server, you can't really install RRAS on windows XP, however you can configure XP to accept incoming connections (limited to 10). Follow [this article](http://www.zdnetasia.com/insight/network/0,39044847,39050037-39000223c-1,00.htm) to get it setup.

On the other hand, if your just trying to get the RRAS console on your machine, for connectivity to RRAS on another server, they all you should need do is install the server 2003 support tools to get this mmc.